# Subset time series to get the start and the end of continuous time series in a list

Tags: r, time-series

It's seems to be easy, but after a long time searching and trying I didn't get it:

I have a list of time series, a short example for reproducing:

```
a <- seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("1970-01-05"), "days")
b <- seq(as.Date("1985-10-01"), as.Date("1985-10-05"), "days")
c <- seq(as.Date("2014-03-01"), as.Date("2014-03-05"), "days")
d <- c(a, b, c)
df1 <- data.frame(d)
colnames(df1) <- c("date")
e <- seq(as.Date("1975-01-01"), as.Date("1975-01-05"), "days")
f <- seq(as.Date("1990-10-01"), as.Date("1990-10-05"), "days")
g <- c(e, f)
df2 <- data.frame(g)
colnames(df2) <- c("date")
ll <- list(df1, df2)
```

Now I want to subset the listed data.frames to:

```
> llsubset
[[1]]
        date
1 1970-01-01
2 1970-01-05
3 1985-10-01
4 1985-10-05
5 2014-03-01
6 2014-03-05

[[2]]
        date
1 1975-01-01
2 1975-01-05
3 1990-10-01
4 1990-10-05
```

I've tried it by `rollapply`, but it doesn't work and it's not worth to see. Maybe you can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determine which points differ from the prior by more than 1 day and from that construct a logical with TRUE at the ends of each sequence and FALSE elsewhere.  Subset by it.  No packages are used.

```
lapply(ll, subset, { dif <- diff(date) > 1; c(TRUE, dif) | c(dif, TRUE) } )
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
         date
1  1970-01-01
5  1970-01-05
6  1985-10-01
10 1985-10-05
11 2014-03-01
15 2014-03-05

[[2]]
         date
1  1975-01-01
5  1975-01-05
6  1990-10-01
10 1990-10-05
```

Comment: I like the use of `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? Use `cumsum` and `diff` to create a group variable and then subset your date (assuming you are trying to find out the min and max date within each consecutive time period and `date` is sorted in ascending order before hand):

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(ll, function(df) {
            df %>% 
                  group_by(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date) != 1))) %>% 
                  slice(c(1, n())) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  select(date) }
      )

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
#        date
#      <date>
#1 1970-01-01
#2 1970-01-05
#3 1985-10-01
#4 1985-10-05
#5 2014-03-01
#6 2014-03-05

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
#        date
#      <date>
#1 1975-01-01
#2 1975-01-05
#3 1990-10-01
#4 1990-10-05
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a package that does exactly this, but I don't yet know its name.

Using `diff()` on the dates can highlight which dates have only one day between them, like so:

```
diff(df1$date)
Time differences in days
 [1]     1     1     1     1  5748     1     1     1     1 10374     1
[12]     1     1     1
```

We can use that.

```
end_finder <- function(x) {
  # find the gap between dates.
  # mark dates where the diff > 1,
  # also mark the entry prior to that one;
  # this will be the end of the previous date.
  # also include the first and last element.

  diff_dates <- c(100,diff(x$dates))
  diff_idx <- which(diff_dates > 1)
  diff_idx <- c((diff_idx -1 ), diff_idx)
  # remove any elements < 1
  diff_idx <- diff_idx[diff_idx >= 1 ]
  # include the first element
  diff_idx <- c(1, diff_idx)
  # include the last element
  diff_idx <- c(diff_idx, length(x$date))
  # remove duplicates and sort for easier reading
  diff_idx <- sort(unique(diff_idx))
  x$dates[diff_idx]
}
```

Now run that.

```
> lapply(ll, end_finder)
[[1]]
[1] "1970-01-01" "1970-01-05" "1985-10-01" "1985-10-05" "2014-03-01"
[6] "2014-03-05"

[[2]]
[1] "1975-01-01" "1975-01-05" "1990-10-01" "1990-10-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `dplyr`: First we compute year for each date and for each year we find the min and max date
using `year` and `melt` functions from lubridate and reshape2 packages respectively

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)

ll <- list(df1, df2)


fn_endPoint_Years = function(DF) {

newDF = DF %>%  
mutate(Year=year(date)) %>% 
group_by(Year) %>% 
do(.,data.frame(minDate=min(.$date),maxDate=max(.$date) )) %>% 
melt(id="Year",value.name = "date") %>% 
arrange(date) %>% 
select(date)

}

lapply(ll,fn_endPoint_Years)

# [[1]]
        # date
# 1 1970-01-01
# 2 1970-01-05
# 3 1985-10-01
# 4 1985-10-05
# 5 2014-03-01
# 6 2014-03-05

# [[2]]
        # date
# 1 1975-01-01
# 2 1975-01-05
# 3 1990-10-01
# 4 1990-10-05
```